# Check if date/period is inside another date(s)/period - is more elegant solution possible?

Tags: php, algorithm, date, calendar

I was wondering if there is an elegant solution to this programming problem.

There is a date of an event that meets the following conditions:

```
1) it can be 'from' - 'to'
2) OR it can be 'from' 
   AND (repeating at defined intervals n times OR indefinitely). 
   The interwals can be day/week/month or year
```

There is a participant on that event. (S)He may have a period/date attached, when (s)he is unavailable.

```
1) the date can be 'from' - 'to'
2) the date can be only 'from'
3) the date can be only 'to'
```

I need to check if participant's 'unavailable' date - if present - overlaps in any way with event date.

For now it's a hotchpotch or conditions. Code's not finished, I'll have to add more. Language - PHP. I'm usding DateTime PHP object for comparing dates.

Can this be improved somehow or conditions are the only way to go in this case? I don't need an exact code, just an idea.

```
    if($event->recurring === '0') {
        // Non recurring event
        if($eventEndValid && $userFromValid && $userToValid) { $user->available = ($userFrom < $eventStart && $userTo < $eventStart) || ($userFrom >= $eventEnd && $userTo > $eventEnd); } 
        else if($userFromValid && $userToValid) { $user->available = ($userFrom < $eventStart) && ($userTo <= $eventStart); }
        else if(!$eventEndValid && !$userToValid) { $user->available = false; }
        else if(!$eventEndValid && !$userFromValid) { $user->available = $userTo <= $eventStart; } 
        else if($eventEndValid && !$userToValid) { $user->available = $userFrom >= $eventEnd; } 
        else if($eventEndValid && !$userFromValid) { $user->available = $userTo <= $eventStart; }
    } else {
        $dIntStr = 'P';
        switch($event->recurring_frequency) {
            case '1':
                $dIntStr .= '1D';
                break;
            case '2':
                $dIntStr .= '1W';
                break;
            case '3':
                $dIntStr .= '1M';
                break;
            case '4':
                $dIntStr .= '1Y';
                break;
        }
        // Case 1
        if(!$userToValid) { $user->available = false; }
        if((!$userFromValid && $userToValid)) { $user->available = $userTo <= $eventStart; }

        // Case 2 - number of intervals is unlimited
        if($event->recurring_frequency === '0') {
            if($userToValid && $userTo <= $eventStart) { $user->available = true; } 
            else if($userTo > $eventStart) {
                // If unavailability is between the intervals then true
                $user->available = true;
            } 
            else { $user->available = false; }
        }


        // Case 2 - number of intervals is limited
        $dateInterval = DateInterval($dIntStr);
        if($event->recurring_frequency === '0') {

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually can use functions to shorten the code. However i'd think a class is more suitable for this:

```
class DateRange{
  public $from, $to;

  public function inBetween($outer){
    return $this->from >= $outer->from && $this->to <= $outer->to;
  }

  function __construct($from, $to){
    if($a = $from->getTimestamp() == $b = $to->getTimestamp()){
      throw new \Exception('A period cannot be the same time');
    } else {
      if($a < $b){
        $this->from = $a;
        $this->to = $b;
      } else {
        $this->from = $b;
        $this->to = $a;
      }
    }
  }
}

$today    = new Datetime();
$lastyear = (new Datetime())->modify('-1 year');
$from     = (new Datetime())->modify('-9 month');

$outer    = new DateRange($lastyear, $today);
$inner    = new DateRange($from, $today);

if($inner->inBetween($outer)){
  echo 'it is';
} else {
  echo 'it isnt';
}
```

You can add more methods like `inBetween()` as you see fit this way.

Comment: Thanks. This approach worked really well. Initially I thought that it will be too much code to create a new class - which is true - but now the code is easier to read and maintainable. The code: [DateRangeHelper class](https://bitbucket.org/al2357/php_snippets/src/d947a38689605ca58d8da3e6a1401b7e37659630/DateRangeHelper/DateRangeHelper.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 0):

I know so long time has passed, but:

```
 /**
 * isInDateRange PHP>=5.3,7,8.0
 *
 * @param  DateTime $startRange
 * @param  DateTime $endRange
 * @param  DateTime $dateTarget
 * @return bool
 */
function isInDatesRange( DateTime $startRange, DateTime $endRange, DateTime $dateTarget) {
    //->some dates range validations if you want to...
    
    if($endRange == $dateTarget) return true;
    
    $interval   = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $range      = new DatePeriod($startRange, $interval, $endRange);

    foreach($range as $day ) {
        if($day->format('Y-m-d') == $dateTarget->format('Y-m-d')) return true;
    }

    return false;
    
}

/**
 * isInDateRange PHP>8.2.0
 *
 * @param  DateTime $startRange
 * @param  DateTime $endRange
 * @param  DateTime $dateTarget
 * @return bool
 */
function isInDatesRange( DateTime $startRange, DateTime $endRange, DateTime $dateTarget) : bool {
    //->some dates range validations if you want to...

    $interval   = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $range      = new DatePeriod($startRange, $interval, $endRange, DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE);

    foreach($range as $day ) {
        if($day->format('Y-m-d') == $dateTarget->format('Y-m-d')) return true;
    }

    return false;
    
}
```